# Theoretical question about span and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a theoretical question about Span, based on a question in my textbook. My answer started the same as that given in the answer key, but then diverges. I am not sure if my original answer is valid, but it is important to know, so that I gain deeper understanding of the subject matter.

$V$ is a vector space over field $F$

$A=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\} \subseteq V$, and $A$ is linearly independent.

$C=\{u_1+u_2,u_2+u_3,u_3+u_1\} \subseteq V$

I am asked to prove that $SpA = SpC$.

Clearly the elements in C are linear combinations of the elements in $A$, and therefore part of $SpA$, and we can easily show that any linear combination of C is also a part of $SpA$ (I have omitted the details/proof, because they are self-evident).

The answer in the textbook then says that $dimSpA=3$ (because the elements in A are linearly independent), and it proves that the elements in C are linearly independent, thus $dimSpC=3$. And as $dimSpA=dimSpC$, $SpC = SpA$.

My own answer continued differently:

I showed that all elements in A are linear combinations of the elements in C:

$(u_1=\frac{1}{2}(u_1+u_2)-\frac{1}{2}(u_2+u_3)+\frac{1}{2}(u_3+u_1)$,

$(u_2=\frac{1}{2}(u_1+u_2)+\frac{1}{2}(u_2+u_3)-\frac{1}{2}(u_3+u_1)$

$(u_3=-\frac{1}{2}(u_1+u_2)+\frac{1}{2}(u_2+u_3)+\frac{1}{2}(u_3+u_1)$

Therefore, $A \subseteq SpC$, and thus per definition all linear combinations of $A$ are a part of $SpC$, i.e. $SpA \subseteq SpC$. We already proved that $spC \subseteq SpA$. If $spC \subseteq SpA$ and $SpA \subseteq SpC$, then $SpA = SpC$.

Is my reasoning valid, and if not, why not?

Thank you!

Comment: Your solution is valid as well.

Comment: @peter
Sorry: my mistake… Initially this was a much longer question involving other sets of vectors as well. I got those parts of the question right, so I left those sets of vectors out, but got confused in the process… I have edited accordingly.